# How to use wi-fi / bluetooth as adaptapter on my PC(desktop)

Tags: windows-7, android, lan, network-adapter, gaming

I know the [USB Tethering mode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eg_tdaTd7QY) in android (Ya, I am talking about `android as OS`) but don't know how to use it to create a LAN to connect with my Laptop (For gaming and file transfer porpouse)

So,I want to know, can we use the WI-fi/Bluetooth adapter in my smartphone to connect my Desktop and Laptop to make a LAN ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand You correctly, you won't to use your smartphone to make a LAN network. USB tethering mode won't help you, because you won't by able to connect more then one device to your phone. Try using your android phone as a hotspot. I have a good experience in LAN gaming when everyone connects to such hotspot.

Comment: I think I saw it... my phone was connected to desktop as well as to my laptop's wi-fi simultaneously using wi-fi hotspot on my phone

Comment: Please explain what do you want to achieve, because I don't understand your problem. Do you want to use your phone as a USB WiFi card?

Comment: I think,...yes.

Comment: Have you tried connecting your phone to desktop, connecting to WiFi with your phone and turning on USB Tethering?

Comment: If you are saying that (Desktop connected to phone and phone's wifi connected to laptop + usb tethring) then yes I tried that